# How to derive session token account using magicblock ts library

Tags: magicblock, session-token, gum

Is there a way to derive the `sessionToken` account using TypeScript.

On react, the closest that I have found is the `useSessionWallet` hook. here https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-examples/blob/7bf574b105629d1cfab7ec30e8a26768143affb4/lumberjack/app/components/SessionKeyButton.tsx#L11

I want to write tests for my program and that is why I need to derive it without a hook.

Answer (score 2):

Hey the PDA is derived from the session key program ("KeyspM2ssCJbqUhQ4k7sveSiY4WjnYsrXkC8oDbwde5"), the string "session_token", then the target program, so the one you deployed and then the authority and the session signer:

```
public static PublicKey DeriveSessionTokenAccount(
      PublicKey authority,
      PublicKey targetProgram,
      PublicKey sessionSigner)
    {
      PublicKey address;
      PublicKey.TryFindProgramAddress((IEnumerable<byte[]>) new List<byte[]>()
      {
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("session_token"),
        (byte[]) targetProgram,
        (byte[]) sessionSigner,
        (byte[]) authority
      }, GplSessionProgram.ProgramIdKey, out address, out byte _);
      return address;
    }
```

Comment: what's the difference between the session signer and the authority? 

do those addresses represent the signer?

Comment: Authority is your wallet, Signer is the temporary keypair that is used to auto sign the transactions.